# Natvis: visualization works in tooltip, not in watch window

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4

The visualizers in natvis are working inconsistently for me, and I could use some help on how to go about debugging them.

I'm using UE4's natvis, but I've added some of visualizations of my own that have the same behavior, so I don't think it's their issue. And of course many people use these successfully.

symptom: the simple visualizers work fine when I mouse-over a variable, but not in the watch,auto or locals windows. The Expand visualizers don't seem to work at all.

With Natvis debugging on 'verbose' if I add the variable by typing its name in the watch window, there's no output. But when I mouse-over it, I do get output that indicates the visualization is being applied:

```
UE4.natvis(208,6): Successfully parsed expression 'ArrayNum == 0' in type context 'TArray<FName,FDefaultAllocator>'.
```

I'm also having issues with the Expand tags. They don't seem to work although the diagnostic implies they do:

```
Successfully parsed expression '(int*)(AllocatorInstance.Data)' in type context 'TArray<int,FDefaultAllocator>'.
```

But all I see is the raw form, which the docs say is what happens on failure.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out there's a non-obvious checkbox that does this.

Tools => Options => General:  "Show raw structure of objects in variables windows"